# Wrong artist on deezer player

Tags: deezer

I'm trying to put a deezer player on a HTML page but the code not seems to do what I want. I've choosed the artist "20' To Live", which have the ID 11483062, so I've got the following source code :

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" src="https://www.deezer.com/plugins/player?format=classic&autoplay=false&playlist=true&width=400&height=350&color=007FEB&layout=dark&size=medium&type=radio&id=artist-11483062&app_id=1" width="400" height="350"></iframe>
```

But the player show an Ed Sheeran playlist...
I don't understand how to fix it.
Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, an "Artist radio" as you selected is not a playlist with all the tracks directly related to the artist, but a personalized radio based on the chosen artist and similar artists and genres, that's why you can have a different artist in the tracklist.

Comment: and what if I want to put a player which plays the music of a choosen artist?

Comment: You have to select the tracks that you want, as there is no "top tracks" direct endpoint.